# Use of Co. in a Non-Registered Business Name

Tags: canada, corporate-law

A few of my friends and I have started a business in Canada, and in our name we have "Co." at the end. We are deciding whether to register as a business or not, and are unsure as to whether we can continue to use `Co." in the name without registering.

In the [choosing a name](https://corporationscanada.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/cd-dgc.nsf/eng/cs01191.html) section of the canada corporation site it states:

> *The accepted way to include a legal element in a corporate name is to add a term to the end of the name such as Limited, Incorporated or Corporation, or contractions of these such as Ltd., Inc. or Corp.*

Does this mean that "Co." indicates a corporation? If so, can we continue to use it if we decide to not register as a corporation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Co is not one of the words or phrases reserved for corporations. You can use it.

> **Canada Business Corporations Act (R.S.C., 1985, c. C-44) Section 10(1)**
>
> The word or expression “Limited”, “Limitée”, “Incorporated”,
>   “Incorporée”, “Corporation” or “Société par actions de régime fédéral”
>   or the corresponding abbreviation “Ltd.”, “Ltée”, “Inc.”, “Corp.” or
>   “S.A.R.F.” shall be part, other than only in a figurative or
>   descriptive sense, of the name of every corporation, but a corporation
>   may use and be legally designated by either the full or the
>   corresponding abbreviated form.

Keep in mind that registering and incorporating are two different things in Canada. The page that you linked to applies specifically to corporations. Not every business is a corporation but most provincial and territorial governments require that you register your business with them.

Comment: This answer is about corporations, not companies. All corporations are companies, but NOT all companies are corporations. That is why you don't see Co. up there.

Comment: So you are saying that a non-corporation can use Ltd or Corp in its name?

Comment: No. But they can use Co.

Comment: Co. Just denotes they are doing business. They are a company. All those things you site are companies, but companies need not be any of those things.

Comment: *No. But they can use Co*  -  Right, so if a non-incorporated company cannot use the words reserved in Section 10, then the section **is** about non-incorporated companies - by exclusion.

Comment: No...it's extraneous, not particularly relevant to this questions, Is all i was getting at. The question was just "does it mean corporation and if not can i use it.  That section is about incorporated companies...not non-inc. ones.

Comment: That's not the approach I was taking. My approach was to identify the reserved words. **The page that OP linked to does not include the full list of legal elements.** I showed the list of *legal elements which indicate the legal status of the corporation as an incorporated body* and since Co. is not on the list it's ok to use.

Comment: I understand. I was confused when you just said, it was about "non-incorporated bodies". Either way, there is not legal element to be a company...that was my point.

Answer (score 1):

Co. is company not corporation. You can do business as a d/b/a and use Co, without doing anything at all. You can register or not (if you have a good name and you want to keep it, register). You should, however, consider creating an LLC no matter whether you're a sole proprietor or 3 friends who make 10k a year: It's cheap and it removes your personal liability. Your company can go bankrupt and your personal property is safe. That is what I would do. You don't even need a lawyer...it's simple. However, to answer your question, you can continue doing what you're doing no problem.